# Remove class when page loads and add class when leaving the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate a div so it appears when I open the page and disappears when I leave the page. 
I was able to make it appear but not disappear. here's what I have:

```
.crvlh{
float: left;
width: 94vw;
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: 10vw;
opacity:1;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, margin-top 0.5s ease-in-out;}

.crvlh.load{
opacity: 0;
margin-top: 13vw;   
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out, margin-top 0.5s ease-in-out;}


$(window).load(function () {$('.crvlh').removeClass('load');});
$(window).unload(function () {$('.crvlh').addClass('load');});
```

Comment: well unload is too late for most things....

Comment: So you want to pause the closing/exiting of a page while you wait for a small animation to play?

Comment: @KhauriMcClain maybe something like that, do you think that's the better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unload` event is fired, after the browser has already hidden the page. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/unload) (emphasis mine):

> The document is in a particular state:
>
> - All the resources still exist (img, iframe etc.)
> - **Nothing is visible anymore to the end user**

In order for the user to see the unloading animation, you need to trigger it earlier.

One way is to use the `beforeunload` event ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload))

Comment: I have no idea how that works ahah but i'll search it! Thanks!! Btw do you think this is a good way to create some animation between pages?